# Scope of variables in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

When I have e.g.

```
type 'a inf_list = Cons of 'a * (unit -> inf_list);; 

(* inf_list starting at n*)
let rec num n = Cons (n, fun () -> num (n+1));;
```

How does the following work:

```
let Cons (cur, rest_l) = integers 1;; 

let x = cur;; 
let y = (rest_l());;
```

normally the format is `let <variable/function-name> = <definition>`.

Here it is `let <type (x,y) = <expression>`. So generally speaking how does this work?

Comment: They're patterns used to destructure values, similar to how in JavaScript you can do `let {x, y} = point`. The variable pattern (single identifier) is just one of many valid patterns you can use. See for example https://cs3110.github.io/textbook/chapters/data/pattern_matching_advanced.html#pattern-matching-with-let

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is a definition like this not producing an error in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951884/why-is-a-definition-like-this-not-producing-an-error-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the form for `let` is `let <pattern> = <expression>`. You can have many things in a `let` besides variable and function names. A name is just one possible kind of pattern.

Second, the subexpression `Cons (cur, rest_l)` is not a type. It's a pattern that matches a value of type `'a inf_list`. The head of the list will be bound to `cur` and the rest of the list will be bound to `rest_l`.

So your example has the expected form for a `let`. And it binds the two names `cur` and `rest_l` in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Jeffrey's answer, please note that the `as` keyword can be used to bind a name to a pattern.

In your case:

```
let Cons (cur, rest_l) as lst = integers 1;;
```

Where `lst` now refers to the entire `inf_list` value as well as binding names to its constituent values.